# reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I've one tableview with different `section` and each section have only one row. if any section is selected video is playing in `MPMoviePlayerviewcontroller`. After click on `Done` button my app is crashing only some times(some sections Particular only).

My code is as below:

```
subcategorytable=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,375,667) style:(UITableViewStylePlain)];
subcategorytable.dataSource=self;
subcategorytable.delegate=self;
subcategorytable.separatorColor=[UIColor orangecolour];
subcategorytable.hidden=YES;
subcategorytable.backgroundView=nil;
[subcategorytable registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"subcatcellid"];
[self.view addSubview:subcategorytable];

     ***cellForRowAtIndexPath***

    static NSString *cellidentifier3 = @"subcatcellid";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier3
                             ];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier3];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[productarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    UIFont * font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:18];
    cell.textLabel.font=font;
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
     cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;

  ***didSelectRowAtIndexPath***

    NSString *strurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[producturl objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];

    strurl=[strurl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strurl];
    NSDictionary *videos = [HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:imageURL];
    if (!movieplayer)
        movieplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[videos objectForKey:@"medium"]]];

    [movieplayer.moviePlayer setControlStyle: MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
    [movieplayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieplayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:movieplayer.moviePlayer];

          ***moviePlayBackDidFinish***

[movieplayer removeFromParentViewController];
movieplayer =  nil;
subcategorytable.hidden=NO;
[subcategorytable reloadData];
```

I've checked a few other questions but still can't figure out why this is happening.

Please tell any one....

Comment: plz add view did load and did appear code.

Comment: check that you are returning non null value in cellForRow

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated` method instead of using `removeFromParentViewController` in your `moviePlayBackDidFinish`.

```
-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
    int value = [[aNotification.userInfo valueForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] intValue];
    if (value == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited) {
        [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
    }
    subcategorytable.hidden=NO;
    [subcategorytable reloadData];
}
```